# Rename directories , softlinks in a specific directory

Tags: bash, directory, rename

My homework is to write a bash script where I type in a directory as a parameter
like `./hw.sh /home/stuff`

If there are any directories I have to rename them like this
**oldname** (`twitch`) **newname** (`twitchdir`)

If there are other things in the directory other than directories their name should  be:
**oldname** (`things.txt`) **newname** (`things.txtetc`)

```
if [ -z $1 ] || ! [ -d $1 ]; then

        echo "ERROR";
else 

        for row in $1/*;
        do
                if [ -d "$row" ]; then
                        mv "$row" "$rowdir"
                else
                        mv "$row" "$rowetc"
                fi
        done
fi
```

If I'm running the script, it's telling me I cannot move the parameter.
The first if is analyzing if the parameter is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

What is causing the errors in your script are `"$rowdir"` and `"$rowetc"`, since you don't have such variables defined. Hence the `mv` command is essentially trying to move a file to an undefined variable's value `''`, which is failing. So if you want to append a string to your original variable's value, do so as follows:

```
mv "$row" "$row"dir           # for directories
mv "$row" "$row"etc           # for others
```

or

```
mv "$row" "${row}dir"           # for directories
mv "$row" "${row}etc"           # for others
```

For example, in a working directory that only contains the file `somefile`, consider,

```
$ ls
somefile
$ row=somefile
$ mv "$row" "$rowetc"
mv: cannot move ‘somefile’ to ‘’: No such file or directory
$ mv "$row" "$row"etc
$ ls
somefileetc
```

Comment: IMHO a cleaner solution would be using braces e.g. `"${row}dir"` to keep everything inside quotes. @PatrikTóth if this has solved your problem you should mark it as accepted, that's how we say thank you around here!